# Batch file for file created date then goto :install

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, if-statement, cmd

Just trying to write a batch syntax that will grab the file created date of a specific file and then if the date is older than 90 days it will move to the next part of the batch script if not, it will end.

So far I can get the date by doing:

For %a in (c:\test.txt) do set myfiledate=%~ta

Comment: use our [Search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+get+yesterday+date) with "get yesterday date". You will find a lot of possible solutions. Tip: calculating with date or time with pure batch is possible, but awful.

Comment: [FORFILES](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)

Comment: PowerShell makes this easy. Use `Get-ChildItem | Get-Member` which has a `LastWriteTime` property.

Comment: Your provided example does not match the intent within your question title. First, your title is specific to 'Batch file' yet your command only works directly in cmd.exe. Second, and more important, your question title specifically asks for 'file created date' and you state that you 'can get the date' but then you use `%~ta` which retrieves the file modified date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not looking for a PowerShell script, but doing date calculations in a cmd.exe script is excessively cumbersome.

There is a file in my directory.

```
C:>Get-ChildItem C:\Users\lit\t.txt

    Directory: C:\Users\lit

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2017-08-14     15:16              0 t.txt
```

Here is the script.

```
C:>Get-Content .\dt2.ps1
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()

$ct = (Get-ChildItem C:\users\lit\t.txt).CreationTime

if ($_.CreationTime -gt [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-90)) {
    Write-Verbose "file is less than 90 days since creation"
    return
}

Write-Verbose "file is more than 90 days since creation"
```

To get the Write-Verbose statements to produce output, run with the `-Verbose` switch.

```
C:>.\dt2.ps1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: file is more than 90 days since creation
```